# R Get minimum value in dataframe selecting rows on 2 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, select, multiple-columns, min

I have a dataframe like the one I've simplified below. I want to first select rows with the same value based on column X, then in that selection select rows with the same value based on column Y. Then from that selection, I want to take the minimal value. I'm now using a forloop, but seems there must be an easier way. Thanks!

```
set.seed(123)    
data<-data.frame(X=rep(letters[1:3], each=8),Y=rep(c(1,2)),Z=sample(1:100, 12))
data
   X Y  Z
1  a 1 76
2  a 1 22
3  a 2 32
4  a 2 23
5  b 1 14
6  b 1 40
7  b 2 39
8  b 2 35
9  c 1 15
10 c 1 13
11 c 2 21
12 c 2 42
```

Desired outcome:

```
   X Y  Z
2  a 1 22
4  a 2 23
5  b 1 14
8  b 2 35
10 c 1 13
11 c 2 21
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
data = data.table(data)
data[, min(Z), by=c("X", "Y")]
```

EDIT based on OP's comment:

If there is a NA value in one of the columns we sort by, an additional row is created:

```
data[2,2] <-NA
data[, min(Z,na.rm = T), by=c("X", "Y")]

   X  Y V1
1: a  1 31
2: a NA 79
3: a  2 14
4: b  1 31
5: b  2 14
6: c  1 50
7: c  2 25
```

Comment: Thank. Is there any downside of changing my dataframe to a data table? Anything I should consider...

Comment: No downside. A data.table is still a data.frame, meaning it can do all the things a data.frame can do, just with some more features. (Anyone correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: And do NAs get ignored? Seems like it does :)

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer with a NA value. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a NA value in column V1. That it takes the minimal value, ignoring that NA. But I think the initial code was correct

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  group_by(X, Y) %>%
  summarise(Z = min(Z))
```

Will do the trick! The other answer right now is the `data.table` way, this is `tidyverse`. Both are extremely powerful ways to approach data cleaning & manipulation - it could be helpful to familiarize yourself with one!

Answer (score 2):

In *base* you can use `aggregate` to get min from `Z` grouped by the remaining columns like:

```
aggregate(Z~.,data,min)
#  X Y  Z
#1 a 1 31
#2 b 1 31
#3 c 1 50
#4 a 2 14
#5 b 2 14
#6 c 2 25
```

In case there is an `NA` in the groups:

```
data[2,2] <-NA
```

Ignore it:

```
aggregate(Z~.,data,min)
#  X Y  Z
#1 a 1 31
#2 b 1 31
#3 c 1 50
#4 a 2 14
#5 b 2 14
#6 c 2 25
```

Show it:

```
aggregate(data$Z, list(X=data$X, Y=addNA(data$Y)), min)
#  X    Y  x
#1 a    1 31
#2 b    1 31
#3 c    1 50
#4 a    2 14
#5 b    2 14
#6 c    2 25
#7 a <NA> 79
```

Comment: Elegant answer. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

This code could benefit from splitting it up in multiple lines, but it works. in Base-R

```
do.call(rbind,
lapply(unlist(lapply(split(data,data$X), function(x) split(x,x$Y)),recursive=F), function(y) y[y$Z==min(y$Z),])
)

    X Y  Z
a.1 a 1 31
a.2 a 2 14
b.1 b 1 31
b.2 b 2 14
c.1 c 1 50
c.2 c 2 25
```